How can i reverse endianess on this function?
I'm trying to parse some data; the function works but gets the endianess wrong.
If I have
Dim bytes As Byte() = {3, 7}

I want to get 0x0307 but instead I got 0x0703.
The same happens with bigger variables.
The function is as follow
Function ParseLocation(data As Byte()) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim datasheet As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

    ' Leer y asignar datos desde el buffer 'data' al 'datasheet'
    datasheet("startBit") = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 0)
    datasheet("protocolLength") = data(2)
    datasheet("protocolNumber") = data(3)
    datasheet("fixTime") = data.Skip(4).Take(6).ToArray() ' Se toma 6 bytes a partir de la posición 4
    datasheet("quantity") = data(10)
    datasheet("lat") = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 11)
    datasheet("lon") = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 15)
    datasheet("speed") = data(19)
    datasheet("course") = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 20)
    datasheet("mcc") = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 22)
    datasheet("mnc") = data(24)
    datasheet("lac") = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 25)
    datasheet("cellId") = Convert.ToInt32(BitConverter.ToString(data, 27, 3).Replace("-", ""), 16)
    datasheet("serialNr") = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 30)
    datasheet("errorCheck") = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 32)

    Return datasheet
End Function

How do I fix this?

This question is similar to: Converting big-endian into little-endian and vice-versa in VBA. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Where are your bytes coming from?  Maybe there is a setting you should change farther upstream to receive the bytes in the correct order?

@Craig Is a GPS tracker and I have no control on the device firmware.

By "device firmware", do you mean a lower-level interface library, or do you literally mean the firmware?  If the latter, then there may still be something that should be happening at the interface level.

@Craig Yes, I'm talking about the device firmware. All the devices are third party.

Then I will say again: we really should be seeing the extra step of how you talk to the firmware.  It may be that bit reversals should be getting done somewhere in that intermediate level.

Is a TCP connection, I can't modify the TCP layers. If the device send &H01 &H02 &H03 &H04 I get exactly that on the byte array.


You can use the BinaryPrimitives (.NET Core 2.1 and later) static class:

Dim bytes As Byte() = {3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1}

Console.WriteLine($"Big Endian (offset 0):    {BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(bytes):X4}")
Console.WriteLine($"Little Endian (offset 0): {BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16LittleEndian(bytes):X4}")

Console.WriteLine($"Big Endian (offset 2):    {BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32BigEndian(bytes.AsSpan(2)):X8}")
Console.WriteLine($"Little Endian (offset 2): {BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32LittleEndian(bytes.AsSpan(2)):X8}")



You can try to find the right byte order in a qword to get a double using combination of these 3 functions:

Private Sub Swap(d As Byte(), x As Integer, y As Integer)
    d(x) = d(x) Xor d(y) : d(y) = d(y) Xor d(x) : d(x) = d(x) Xor d(y)
End Sub

Public Sub SwapBytesOfWords(d As Byte())
    Swap(d, 0, 1) : Swap(d, 2, 3) : Swap(d, 4, 5) : Swap(d, 6, 7)
End Sub

Public Sub SwapWordsOfDwords(d As Byte())
    Swap(d, 0, 2) : Swap(d, 1, 3) : Swap(d, 4, 6) : Swap(d, 5, 7)
End Sub

Public Sub SwapDWordsOfQword(d As Byte())
    Swap(d, 0, 4) : Swap(d, 1, 5) : Swap(d, 2, 6) : Swap(d, 3, 7)
End Sub

For example, like this:
Dim d = BitConverter.GetBytes(1234.5678)
Console.WriteLine($"Original order:       {BitConverter.ToUInt64(d):X16}, Double: {BitConverter.ToDouble(d)}")
SwapBytesOfWords(d)
Console.WriteLine($"Swap bytes of words:  {BitConverter.ToUInt64(d):X16}, Double: {BitConverter.ToDouble(d)}")
SwapWordsOfDwords(d)
Console.WriteLine($"Swap words of dwords: {BitConverter.ToUInt64(d):X16}, Double: {BitConverter.ToDouble(d)}")
SwapDWordsOfQword(d)
Console.WriteLine($"Reverse order:        {BitConverter.ToUInt64(d):X16}, Double: {BitConverter.ToDouble(d)}")


Thanks but I'm using NET 4.8 and span of bytes is deprecated(unsafe method). Now I'm just using Array.Copy and some other methods; is a longer code but is starting to work.

The methods I have proposed use for Big Endian the intermediate ReverseEndianness method. So maybe you don't lose anything.

I need to obtain a numerical variable to make some calculus and get a Double at the end so I tried this Dim startIndex As Integer = 30
datasheet("serialNr") = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(data(startIndex)) and didn't worked, and even tried to create a span of bytes and that's when the VS IDE said nope!

@E_Blue, I added functions to my answer to obtain a double.

I've just extracted the bytes that I need for every variable and converted in to a String and then to a decimal and with that I perform a calculus that gave me a Double.

GPS trackers send coordinates in one of the following formats: dd.ddddddd, ddd mm.mmmmm, ddd mm ss.sss or in some units corresponding to a very small fraction of a degree. Any conversions there via a string are redundant.

They send bytes that need low level bit handling, if you try to decode them as ASCII you will see garbage. The protocol is called GT06. The device also supports another protocol that is called TQ that sends all in plain text but I don't know what ACK is expecting and what commands support in that protocol mode. There's no info on the internet and the contact that my boss has is only from a seller. He doesn't know this low level info. The TQ protocol is something like this *HQ,1054115795,V6,151202,V,3534.2406,S,5939.5911,W,0.00,268.00,290424,FFFFFBFF,722,07,4508,103224127,8954079900016945393F,#

If your device can simultaneously send data using the GT06 and TQ protocols, and you have almost figured out the GT06 protocol, then the TQ protocol will be easy to figure out.

The device can send data in only one protocol, you can choose GT06 or TQ. I don't have much problem decoding de data but I have no idea how an ACK to that packet looks like and also I doesn't have the command list in TQ mode.
